# Redacting Log Content

Tags: audit.net

In Audit.Net, is it possible to filter request bodies being saved containing sensitive data? This is for Audit.WebAPI.

E.g., There's a JSON request body with `{"username": "me", "password": "sensitive"}`. Can the password value "sensitive" be replaced by ""?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a custom action that sanitizes the body string on the audit event.

For example:

```
using Audit.WebApi;

Audit.Core.Configuration.AddCustomAction(ActionType.OnScopeCreated, scope =>
{
    var action = scope.GetWebApiAuditAction();
    var bodyString = action?.RequestBody?.Value?.ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyString))
    {
        action.RequestBody.Value = Sanitize(bodyString);
    }
});
```

Using a regular expression:

```
private string Sanitize(string input)
{
    var pattern = @"\s*\""password\"" *: *\"".*\""(,|(?=\s+\}))";
    var substitution = @"""password"": """"";
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
    return regex.Replace(input, substitution);
}
```